# How can I organize similar adapters?

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have three activities: `A`, `B` and `C`. 
Each activity has three tabs: `a`, `b`, `c`. 
Each tab contains ListView with orders.

In total I have 9 listviews, and the elements in each listview are similar, but they have some differences from one listview to another.

My approach is: create one parent `BaseApapter` class, extended from ArrayAdapter, with common things in it getView method, and 9 child OrderAdapters, which implement differences. Does my approach good? I'm confused with large number childs of `BaseAdapter`. What approaches also can be?

Update:
I can't show any code, but can describe it in more detail. Below short description of one listview item in each tab:

1. Activity `A` tab `a` contains such textviews: paramA, paramB, time, distance, price
2. Activity `A` tab `b` contains paramA, paramB, time, distance, price, comment
3. Activity `A` tab `c` contains paramA, paramB, time, distance, price, description
4. Activity `B` tab `a` contains paramA, paramB, time, price (here price font style is different from Activity A)
5. Activity `B` tab `b` contains paramA, paramB, time, price (here price font style is different from Activity A), comment
6. Activity `B` tab `c` contains paramA, paramB, time, price (here price font style is different from Activity A), description
7. Activity `C` tab `a` contains paramA, paramB, imageView avatar, shortNote. This listView item has different background from Activity `A` and `B`.
8. Acitvity `C` tab `b` contains paramA, paramB, imageView avatar, shortNote. This listView item has different background from Activity `A` and `B`.
9. Acitvity `C` tab `c` contains paramA, paramB, imageView avatar, shortNote. This listView item has different background from Activity `A` and `B`

Comment: can you provide some code? for instance to see what those differences are

Comment: If the list you're using contains different objects then for each list new adapter

Comment: @Victor I'm update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create only one adapter because the only difference is in the `getView()` method, so you would have to create 9 items xml files.

Your adapter should contain a parameter to indicate which list view has been instantiated and switch the parameter value to choose which XML you use to inflate the specific layout.

I hope this can help you.